# Panel Data in R - Can I implement a plm regression with categorical data?

Tags: r, categorical-data, panel-data, roc, plm

I am working (In R) on a panel modelling of an econometric problem.

I have :

- one dependent variable : Y with values in real positive numbers
- two explanatory variables : VAR_1 (real positive), VAR_2 (categorical with modalities : class_1,...,class_3)

Each variable has two dimensions (individual, time)

I have two questions:

- Can I use plm method for explaining Y by VAR_1 and VAR_2 ?
- In this panel framework, can I plot a "kind" of ROC curve to compare model 1 and 2 defined as follows :
  *** Model 1 : dummy_Y ~ VAR_1
  *** Model 2 : dummy_Y ~ VAR_1 + VAR_2

In my second question (about ROC curve), Y in models 1 and 2 must be
transformed into dummy (0 if Y=1 and Y=1 if Y>0). By doing so, is it
possible to still use plm method, and have ROC curve ?

Comment: There are statistical questions here, which keeps your question on-topic here so far as I can see. You'd make your question more widely readable if you explained what `plm` does in R.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your comments. plm is a command in R which is used to implement a panel data modelling.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that adds much to your question, I've edited it to be a little clearer, yet it's better attempted by others who know the software.

Comment: You can use categorial variables (factors in R) with the function `plm` of the package `plm`.